# MariaDB SQL performance issue with index

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mariadb

We have a table for looking up IP Geo-Location on MariaDB mariadb-5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 as below:

> > CREATE TABLE `ip2location_db24` (
> >       `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> >       `ip_from` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `ip_to` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `country_code` char(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `country_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `region_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `city_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `zip_code` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `time_zone` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `isp` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `domain` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `net_speed` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `idd_code` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `area_code` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `weather_station_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `weather_station_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `mcc` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `mnc` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `mobile_brand` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `elevation` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
> >       `usage_type` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
> >       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
> >       KEY `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
> >       KEY `idx_latitude` (`latitude`),
> >       KEY `idx_longitude` (`longitude`),
> >       KEY `idx_ip_from_to_2` (`ip_to`,`ip_from`)
> >     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9541211 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

ip_from and ip_to column defines the starting and ending boundaries per geo location.

We have about 10 million records in this table.

When querying geo location for a given IP, we find the server suffers a serious performance issue with the following SQL:

> > select * from ip2location_db24 where  ip_to >=1908980838 and ip_from <=1908980838 limit 1;
> >      *************************** 1. row *************************** 
> >                      id: 5475739 
> >                 ip_from: 1908932608
> >                   ip_to: 1909063679
> >             country_code: CN
> >             country_name: CHINA
> >              region_name: SHANXI
> >                city_name: TAIYUAN
> >                 latitude: 37.86944
> >                longitude: 112.56028
> >                 zip_code: -
> >                time_zone: +08:00
> >                      isp: CHINA UNICOM SHANNXI PROVINCE NETWORK
> >                   domain: CHINAUNICOM.COM
> >                net_speed: DSL
> >                 idd_code: 86
> >                area_code: 0351
> >     weather_station_code: CHXX0129
> >     weather_station_name: TAIYUAN
> >                      mcc: 460
> >                      mnc: 01/06
> >             mobile_brand: CHINA UNICOM
> >                elevation: 787
> >               usage_type: ISP/MOB
> >     1 row in set (15.08 sec)

However, when querying using the following equivalent SQL, its very fast.

> > select * from ip2location_db24 where ip_from <=1908980838 order by ip_from desc limit 1 \G
> >     *************************** 1. row ***************************
> >                       id: 5475739
> >                  ip_from: 1908932608
> >                    ip_to: 1909063679
> >             country_code: CN
> >             country_name: CHINA
> >              region_name: SHANXI
> >                city_name: TAIYUAN
> >                 latitude: 37.86944
> >                longitude: 112.56028
> >                 zip_code: -
> >                time_zone: +08:00
> >                      isp: CHINA UNICOM SHANNXI PROVINCE NETWORK
> >                   domain: CHINAUNICOM.COM
> >                net_speed: DSL
> >                 idd_code: 86
> >                area_code: 0351
> >     weather_station_code: CHXX0129
> >     weather_station_name: TAIYUAN
> >                      mcc: 460
> >                      mnc: 01/06
> >             mobile_brand: CHINA UNICOM
> >                elevation: 787
> >               usage_type: ISP/MOB
> >     1 row in set (0.00 sec)

The problem is, when we check out the execution plan, both of the queries uses the same range scan on index of ip_from column. But these two SQLs' performance are far from close. Anyone has any idea on reason of this?

To provide more information, we also tested query whose output columns are completely covered by indexes.

> > MariaDB [ip2location]  select ip_from,ip_to from ip2location_db24 where  ip_to >=1908980838 and ip_from <=1908980838 limit 1; 
> >     +------------+------------+
> >     | ip_from    | ip_to      |
> >     +------------+------------+
> >     | 1908932608 | 1909063679 |
> >     +------------+------------+
> >     1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Note the above query SQL is lightning fast. But when querying any additional column not covered by indexes, it takes unbelievable long period of time:

> >
>   MariaDB [ip2location] select ip_from,ip_to,country_code from ip2location_db24 where  ip_to >=1908980838 and ip_from <=1908980838 limit 1;
>   +------------+------------+--------------+
>   | ip_from    | ip_to      | country_code |
>   +------------+------------+--------------+
>   | 1908932608 | 1909063679 | CN           |
>   +------------+------------+--------------+
>   1 row in set (10.15 sec)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ip2location_db24 where ip_to >=1908980838 and ip_from <=1908980838 limit 1;
```

Slow because of comparison two columns.

```
select * from ip2location_db24 where ip_from <=1908980838 order by ip_from desc limit 1
```

Fast because of only one indexed column is compared.

Answer (score -1):

Try `force index` as described in the MariaDB manual section *[Forcing an index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/query-optimizations/how-to-force-query-plans/#dont-use-a-particular-index)*:

```
select ip_from,ip_to,country_code
from ip2location_db24 force index (idx_ip_from_to_2)
where ip_to >=1908980838 and ip_from <=1908980838
limit 1;
```